# How to populate an array in side a model for postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, asp.net-mvc, model

I have a model that contains a List of `Milestone`, I want that list to be populated (inside the model) with a given set of Textboxes in the webpage.

```
public class Project
{
    public string ProjectNumber { get; set; }
    public IList<Parameter> Parameters;
    public IList<Milestone> MilestoneList = new List<Milestone>();
}
```

And inside my `Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { Project = Model }))` I have the following TextBox.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.MilestoneList.Count; i++)
{  
    <td style="align-content: center;">@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.MilestoneList[i].Value)</td>
}
```

My problem in my controller below the milestonelist is always `null` in model Project

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Project project)
{
    helper.CreateProject(project, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
    return View();
}
```

So how should I program so the list inside the model will be populated through TextBoxes?

Answer (score 2):

Your using fields in the model, not properties, so the `DefaultModelBinder` cannot **set** the value. Change you model to

```
public class Project
{
    public string ProjectNumber { get; set; }
    public IList<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }
    public IList<Milestone> MilestoneList { get; set; }
}
```

and initialize the collection in in the controller.